# How can I build gettext 64bit dll on Windows.

Tags: 64-bit, gettext, msys, mingw-w64

I succeeded to build gettext 32bit dll on Windows.

I installed these.
gettext-0.18.11
mingw (include msys)

```
./configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads=win32 --enable-relocatable
cd gettext-runtime
make
```

But I don't know how to build 64bit dll.

Someone said I should use mingw64. Then I installed mingw64 and msys.

But I don't know how to do setting mingw64 and msys to build 64bit dll.
And I don't know gettext configure option to build 64bit dll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download latest MinGW-w64 targeting 64-bit (there are also targeting 32-bit, so be careful) **[here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)**.

   **NOTE:** As you added `--enable-threads=win32`, then probably you would be interested in the distribution with Win32 threading support, rather than POSIX, so be cautious when you choose which one to download.
2. Configure in almost the same way, but with addition of one option:

   ```
   ./configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads=win32 --enable-relocatable
   ```
3. Lean back. `:)`

Comment: Personally, I always add the `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` option. Which can be redundant with `--build` for most of the `configure` scripts, but necessary for some others... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First download gettex from here: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

then add system var `PATH: C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin`
afterwards
create in your project a folder that bears the note of
 `locale/`
afterwards
add variable in settings.py:  `LOCALE_PATHS = (BASE_DIR + 'locale/', )`
and
finally try to run
`python manage.py makemessages -l fr`